# Dictionary based search optimization in Java

Tags: java, optimization, dictionary

I have a `Sentences` class. The instance of this class represents each sentence in a text file.

I am reading each sentence from the file and making that sentence an `instance` of my `Sentences` class. For each sentence, I need to check how many stop words/ function words are in it.

I have a text file (`stopwords.txt`) that contains English stop words.

How should I design my program so that for each sentence I don't have to read the `stopwords.txt` file again and again? Rather I should keep the contents of this file (the stopwords) saved "somehow" and then check which of the words of my sentence are stop words.

I have so many sentences that I need this program to be as fast as possible.

### EDIT:

I have created a StopWords class

```
public class StopWords
```

and I am reading the stopwords.txt file in this class and keeping them in a HashSet.

```
....    
while ((entries = br.readLine()) != null){
                    stopWordSet.add(entries.toLowerCase());
...
```

Then, I am creating an instance of my StopWords class in my Sentences class:

```
public class Sentences {
...
    private static StopWords stopList = new StopWords("languageresources/stopword.txt");
...
}
```

I am reading sentences from a file and creating an instance of Sentences class. The words of each of these sentences are kept in an ArrayList named wordList and it is sent to dealStopWord () method of StopWords class to check which of the words are stop words. Finally, I am getting the number of stopwords using getStopWordCount() method:

```
stopList.dealStopWord(wordList);
            this.totalFunctionWords = stopList.getStopWordCount();
```

Edit: If I make the stopList variable local to Sentences class, then for each sentence, the constructor is called (i.e., the stopwords.txt file is read for each sentence) but it is much faster than the case where the stopList variable is static (i.e., when stopwords.txt is read just once)

EDIT

StopWords.java class

```
    public class StopWords {

    //Instance variables
    private String stopWordFile = ""; // name of the stopword file
    private Set<String> stopWordSet; 
    private int count = 0; //number of stopwords found in a given sentence
    private String[] sortedStopWords;
    private ArrayList <String> noStopWordArray = new ArrayList <String> ();

    //Constructor: takes the file containing stopwords
    public StopWords (String fileName){
        System.out.println("Stoplist constructor called");
        this.stopWordFile = fileName;
        FileReader stopWordFile = null;
        try {
            stopWordFile = new FileReader(this.stopWordFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(stopWordFile);
        String entries;
        stopWordSet = new TreeSet<String>();
        try {
            while ((entries = br.readLine()) != null){
                stopWordSet.add(entries.toLowerCase());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sortedStopWords = new String[stopWordSet.size()];
        int i = 0;
        Iterator<String> itr = stopWordSet.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()){
            sortedStopWords[i++] = itr.next();
        }//end while

    }//public StopWords (String fileName)

    //return number of stopwords in a sentence (the sentence comes in as an arraylist of words)
    public void dealStopWord(ArrayList <String> wordArray){

        this.count = 0;
        String temp = "";
        int size = wordArray.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            temp = wordArray.get(i).toLowerCase();
            int found = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedStopWords, temp);
            if(found >= 0){
                this.count++;
            }//end if
            else{
                this.noStopWordArray.add(wordArray.get(i));
            }

        }//while(itr.hasNext())     

    }

    public ArrayList <String> getNoStopWordArray(){

        return this.noStopWordArray;

    }//public ArrayList <String> getNoStopWordArray()

    public int getStopWordCount(){

        return this.count;

    }//public int getStopWordCount()

}//public class StopWords
```

Part of Sentences.java class:

```
       public class Sentences { 
        static StopWords stopList = new StopWords("languageresources/stopword.txt");
    public void setFunctionAndContentWords(){
            //If I make stopList variable locally here, the code is much faster
            stopList.dealStopWord(this.wordList); //at this point, the # of stop words and the sentence without stop word is generated
            this.totalFunctionWords = stopList.getStopWordCount(); //setting the feature here.
            //...set up done.
        }// end method
}
```

And this is how I am creating instance of Sentences class:

```
Sentences[] s = new Sentences[totalSentences]; //sentence object..
       for (int i = 0; i < totalSentences; i++){

                    System.out.println("Processing sentence # " + (i+1));


        s[i].setFunctionAndContentWords();
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you need a database?

Comment: _How should I design_ questions are generally off topic for SO.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, I don't have a choice for keeping  database.

Comment: Even an embedded one?

Comment: you could store stopwords.txt in some Java collection

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, no, I have to do it without using any database.

Comment: @Mysterion, I have created a class StopWords and there I have read the stopwords.txt file and kept all the stopwords in a Java Collection. Then I created an instance variable of StopWords class inside Sentences class. But every time I am creating a Sentences instance, the entire stopword.txt file is read.

Comment: @RushdiShams, make this class outside of Sentence, so it will read stopwords.txt only once

Comment: @Mysterion I have edited the question with some code snippets.

Comment: No it only reads them once when the static variable is initialized at class load time. However you might want to use a different data structure for stopwords than a linear list which is slow to search.

Comment: You know you can always use a debugger or println to see how often the class constructor is called.

Comment: @eckes, that is why I have made this variable static. And I have checked that it is called just once. But it is slow. Interestingly, if I make it local variable, the constructor is called for every sentence but it runs much much faster. What can be the reason?

Comment: What part is slow? Do you use it multithreaded? Does it produce the same results?

Comment: @eckes, it is a single thread environment. Without modifying anything else, if the variable is static, the program is slow and it takes hours to process 2000 sentences. But if the variable is local, then it takes 7 mins to process 2000 sentences. The results are same.

Comment: I think you need to shorten your code to show it completely, otherwise it is hard to speculate what the reason is (but I really cant think of any). It would be interesting where your loops are in the overall code. What does the count do?

Comment: @eckes I have provided some code snippets. Please check the last edit.

Comment: Ah found your problem, you are adding your result to `noStopWordsArray` which is getting bigger and bigger if you don't instantiate the `StopWords` for each run. I think you should not keep any state in that class anyway.

Comment: So, you are saying that I keep the instance variable noStopWordsArray but instantiate it only inside dealStopWords() method?

Comment: There are multiple ways, I would not keep any of the processing logic in the StopWords class. But if you do, make sure to reset the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `StopWords` instance does not accumulate information or is reset. I would make it entirely stateless (no counter and especially no list of unmatched words).

This also has the advantage that you can use it multi-threaded.

In your case this:

```
this.noStopWordArray.add(wordArray.get(i));
```

leads to ever growing array (which is a bigger problem in the static case as you re-use the array for multiple sentences).

Comment: It worked! I was about to lose my faith on static... just for my silly mistake! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use a HashSet.  Put all the stop words into a HashSet before you begin reading the sentences.  Then for each word check if the word is a stop word using:

```
stopWordsHashSet.contains(word);
```

Comment: Maybe a hashmap? Something like HashMap <Sentence, ResultObject>

Comment: HashMap or HashSet will work.  But you would use a HashMap if it is mapping to something else.  If there is no mapping, then save memory by using a HashSet.

Comment: @JoseMartinez I have done what you suggested. Can you look at the EDITs I made and suggest what could possibly cause the "slowness" of the program?

Comment: Sure thing, will take a look.